# how to retrieve record%type table in jdbc?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, plsql

how to retrieve a table of record%type in jdbc. when I run the java code i am getting ORA-04043: object "PERSON_TB" does not exist.

the packages compiled successfully:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MYPKG AS 
TYPE personrec IS RECORD(
        id VARCHAR2(10));
  type_person_rec personrec;
  TYPE person_tb IS TABLE OF type_person_rec%TYPE;
PROCEDURE callproc(persondata OUT person_tb);
END MYPKG;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MYPKG AS
PROCEDURE callproc(persondata OUT person_tb) AS

lv_persondata person_tb;
BEGIN
lv_persondata(1).id := '123';
persondata := lv_persondata;
lv_persondata.DELETE;
END callproc;
END MYPKG;
```

the below is the java code to fetch out parameter:

```
String sql = "{call mypkg.callproc(?)}";
stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.ARRAY,"PERSON_TB");
stmt.execute();
```

this is the error i am getting:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-04043: object "PERSON_TB" does not exist

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.checkError(T2CConnection.java:777)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.checkError(T2CConnection.java:673)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.getTdoCState(T2CConnection.java:876)
at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.initMetadata(OracleTypeADT.java:523)
at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.init(OracleTypeADT.java:471)
at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.initPickler(ArrayDescriptor.java:1627)
at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.<init>(ArrayDescriptor.java:243)
at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:154)
at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:123)
at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:106)
at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:73)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.otypeFromName(NamedTypeAccessor.java:84)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.TypeAccessor.initMetadata(TypeAccessor.java:90)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.allocateAccessor(OracleStatement.java:2458)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CCallableStatement.allocateAccessor(T2CCallableStatement.java:1562)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CCallableStatement.registerOutParameterInternal(T2CCallableStatement.java:1921)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:223)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatementWrapper.java:1595)
```

Comment: Try MYPKG.PERSON_TB in the register call, or move the type declaration out of the package.

Comment: I tried as you suggested. I'm still facing the same issue and the error is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-04043: object "MYPKG"."PERSON_TB" does not exist.

Comment: where is p_call_eaload define?  Pleas show it

Comment: sorry I've corrected the code now

Comment: @OldProgrammer like you suggested I've moved the declaration out of the package and it worked. thank you so much. could you please post it as a solution? I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try MYPKG.PERSON_TB in the register call, or move the type declaration out of the package